# ESP8266 Sleep & Wake from a single button

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, esp8266

Separately putting to sleep & waking the device up is simple.
If I wish to put the device to sleep, do a pull-up to a switch that goes to GND. Attach an interrupt and you're golden.
Waking is the same story but on the specific RST pin.

Is there a way to do both actions on a single/switch button?

Currently, it seems impossible to me and the best I have come up with is to attach the interrupt and wake after a period of time, checking if we are pulled high and if not going back to sleep.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sleep modes, except the very deepest, are usually cancelled whenever interrupts happen.